# What is the effect of Dynamic URL's on SEO

Tags: seo, search-engines, url

I have around 150 dynamic URL's as below

```
http://mydomain.com/training/register.php?key=01ue3be299a-6bc1-1030-a2db-e4115bd593d8
http://mydomain.com/training/register.php?key=02ue3be299a-9bc1-1030-a2db-e4115bd593d8
.
.
.
http://mydomain.com/training/register.php?key=150ue3be299a-10bc1-1030-a2db-e4115bd593d8
```

All the Urls land in the same page, but the content will be different based on the parameter.

**1) Is there any effect of these URL's on SEO. If so What is the solution.?**

and

**2) Can I do URL rewrite ?**

Answer (score 1):

If the content is different at each URL, then Googlebot will treat each URL as its own page.   If you have different URLs and different content, you will have multiple pages in the Google index.

But you might not want all the versions indexed.  It sounds like they are registration pages for different groups of people or for different purposes.  Maybe you only want one registration page to show in Google.  In that case use the [rel canonical meta tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) on all of them to tell Googlebot which is the one that you would like in the index.

You could also use [Google Webmaster Tools under "configuration" -> "URL parameters"](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters) to tell Googlebot that the parameter "key" has no effect on the page and that it should crawl "one representative URL".

Answer (score 0):

Yes defiantly you have to rewrite your URL with the use of htaccess. SEO friendly URLs are very important for ranking.

With the help of SEO friendly URL you can get higher ranking in Search engines.

Search engines can't understand URL like this...

```
http://www.domain.com/services.php?name=SEO
```

but it understand URL like this...

```
http://www.domain.com/SEO
```

This is very helpful. **on above ex**. you can get rank on keyword `SEO` with the help of rewrited URL

Comment: URLs that contain query strings are less descriptive and less usable, and thus less preferred by Google. But Google is perfectly capable of understanding URLs containing query strings. They are legal URLs, and if you perform any search on Google, you'll see many indexed pages (even high ranking ones) that use query strings. Google understands query strings so well that it will even try to find hidden pages by guessing at your query parameters.